# VBA - Calling a function to return boolean to check if file exists

Tags: vba

I am writing a VBA programme to check if a file exists through a function which return boolean. However, I have trouble with the line "File = FileExists(strDataFileName, strDataPath)", the VBA reports the problem was due to mismatch of type. I really have no idea how to fix it. Please help guys.

p.s. sorry the code maybe a bit messy as I am an amateur in VBA programming

```
Function FileExists(ByVal sPathName As String, Optional Directory As Boolean) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
If sPathName <> "" Then
   If IsMissing(Directory) Or Directory = False Then
      FileExists = (Dir$(sPathName) <> "")
   Else
      FileExists = (Dir$(sPathName, vbDirectory) <> "")
   End If
End If
End Function

Sub AH()
Const strDataPath As String = "C:\Users\"
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strDataFileName As String
Dim File As Boolean
Dim ExistWS as boolean
Dim wbNew As Workbook

strDataFileName = "Past Data"
File = FileExists(strDataFileName, strDataPath)
If File = False Then
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    SheetName = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName
    wbNew.SaveAs Filename:=(strDataPath & strDataFileName), FileFormat:=52
    wbNew.Close
Else 
    Cells(2,3) = “TRUE”
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second parameter requires a boolean to designate if it's a directory.
This replacement on that line should then work:

`File = FileExists(strDataPath & strDataFileName, false)`

Comment: Thz Jimmy! it works now! reali thz for yr timely help!

Answer (score 0):

Your second parameter is a boolean. Reading your code i think that maybe if you change it to a String you will make it.

```
Function FileExists(ByVal sPathName As String, Optional Directory As String) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
If sPathName <> "" Then
   If IsMissing(Directory) Or Directory = "" Then
      FileExists = (Dir$(sPathName) <> "")
   Else
      FileExists = (Dir$(vbDirectory & sPathName) <> "")
   End If
End If
End Function
```

Don't forget to especify your file extension at your Sub.